# Unable to get the logs from my application through Opentelemetery Collector configuration to Apache Skywalking

Tags: open-telemetry-collector, otel, skywalking

**This is my Otelcol config file**

receivers:
otlp:
protocols:
grpc:

processors:
batch:
exporters:
otlp:
endpoint: "localhost:11800"
tls:
insecure: true
logging:
loglevel: debug

service:
pipelines:
metrics:
receivers: [otlp]
processors: [batch]
exporters: [logging,otlp]

**This is my skywalking configuration file**

receiver-sharing-server:
selector: ${SW_RECEIVER_SHARING_SERVER:default}
default:

```
# For HTTP server
restHost: ${SW_RECEIVER_SHARING_REST_HOST:0.0.0.0}
restPort: ${SW_RECEIVER_SHARING_REST_PORT:0}
restContextPath: ${SW_RECEIVER_SHARING_REST_CONTEXT_PATH:/}
restMaxThreads: ${SW_RECEIVER_SHARING_REST_MAX_THREADS:200}
restIdleTimeOut: ${SW_RECEIVER_SHARING_REST_IDLE_TIMEOUT:30000}
restAcceptQueueSize: ${SW_RECEIVER_SHARING_REST_QUEUE_SIZE:0}
httpMaxRequestHeaderSize: ${SW_RECEIVER_SHARING_HTTP_MAX_REQUEST_HEADER_SIZE:8192}

# For gRPC server
gRPCHost: ${SW_RECEIVER_GRPC_HOST:0.0.0.0}
gRPCPort: ${SW_RECEIVER_GRPC_PORT:0}
maxConcurrentCallsPerConnection: ${SW_RECEIVER_GRPC_MAX_CONCURRENT_CALL:0}
maxMessageSize: ${SW_RECEIVER_GRPC_MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE:0}
gRPCThreadPoolQueueSize: ${SW_RECEIVER_GRPC_POOL_QUEUE_SIZE:0}
gRPCThreadPoolSize: ${SW_RECEIVER_GRPC_THREAD_POOL_SIZE:0}
gRPCSslEnabled: ${SW_RECEIVER_GRPC_SSL_ENABLED:false}
gRPCSslKeyPath: ${SW_RECEIVER_GRPC_SSL_KEY_PATH:""}
gRPCSslCertChainPath: ${SW_RECEIVER_GRPC_SSL_CERT_CHAIN_PATH:""}
gRPCSslTrustedCAsPath: ${SW_RECEIVER_GRPC_SSL_TRUSTED_CAS_PATH:""}
authentication: ${SW_AUTHENTICATION:""}
```

receiver-otel:
selector: ${SW_OTEL_RECEIVER:default}
default:
enabledHandlers: ${SW_OTEL_RECEIVER_ENABLED_HANDLERS:"oc,otlp,otlp-logs"}
enabledOtelRules: ${SW_OTEL_RECEIVER_ENABLED_OTEL_RULES:"apisix,k8s/*,istio-controlplane,vm,mysql/*,postgresql/*,oap,aws-eks/*,windows,aws-s3/*,aws-dynamodb/*"}

**While running the opentelemetry collector using otel configuration file below is the command that i am using**

C:\otelcol.exe --config C:\opentelemetry-collector\otelcol\otelcol_configuration.yaml

**Getting this error**
2023-12-04T20:44:40.603+0530    warn    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:195  [core] [Channel #1 SubChannel #2] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {Addr: "localhost:11800", ServerName: "localhost:11800", }. Err: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing: dial tcp [::1]:11800: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."  {"grpc_log": true}

I tried to read logs from my application and push them into Apache Skywalking using opentelemetry collector